# replacing first pattern using sed

Tags: sed

I have a cron job with below details

The timing section is unknown, it might be hourly or daily.

```
cat zyx.txt

SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
0 * * * * root /usr/local/bin/log-cleaner
```

I have to update it on the fly using sed, so that it should run every minute .

Here is what I have tried

```
sed -in 's/\(.*\) \(.*\) \(.*\)/\* \* \* \* \*/1' zyx.txt
```

But it is removing the user and path section

```
cat zyx.txt

SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
* * * * *
```

Any help / suggestion using sed is much appreciated

Comment: `sed 's/^0/*/' zyx.txt`?

Comment: but there might be case if the timing might be daily 0 0 * * *, the pattern is unknown . so I am trying to replace the timing section.

Comment: `sed 's/.* root/* * * * * root/' zyx.txt`?

Comment: I misinterpreted your question earlier. If you want to run it every minute and are just having basic regex trouble, simply rewriting the whole line will work. The reason your first expression doesn't work is you wipe out the entire line and just replace it with asterisks -- you put the info you lost in capture groups that you never use later